# Is it possible to convert byte [] to HttpPostedFile?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to convert a byte[] to a HttpPostedFile?

```
System.Web.HttpPostedFile objFile = fileData;
```

where fileData is a byte array of an image, gives a "can not be implicitly converted error".

Comment: Before going any further, this message is telling you it can't cast it *implicitly*. You should first try casting it *explicitly*, like this: `HttpPostedFile objFile = (HttpPostedFile)fileData;`

Comment: hate to sound so rude and upfront but a simple google search will yield the results as well as an example on what you are trying to do..
here is the link [MSDN httpPostedFile.InputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan that's the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do

Comment: @rogerdeuce then try `casting the object` properly and let us know if that solves your issue..

Comment: @MethodMan nope can't cast it either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [the source for the class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpPostedFile.cs,4278efada0d8dbc4) you'll see a few things.

1. The constructor is `internal`, so you'll never directly construct an instance.
2. The class has *minimal* functionality.
3. The class is `sealed`, so you can't add your own constructor using inheritance.

Instead of trying to convert a byte array into an instance of `HttpPostedFile`, you'll have a much smoother experience by converting your downstream methods to accept `byte[]` as input, or maybe `Stream`. If you need the other properties of `HttpPostedFile`, then you could just send them in directly as additional parameters, or write your own class to wrap them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,worked for me

```
public HttpPostedFile ConstructHttpPostedFile(byte[] data, string filename, string contentType)
        {
            // Get the System.Web assembly reference
            Assembly systemWebAssembly = typeof(HttpPostedFileBase).Assembly;
            // Get the types of the two internal types we need
            Type typeHttpRawUploadedContent = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent");
            Type typeHttpInputStream = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpInputStream");
    
            // Prepare the signatures of the constructors we want.
            Type[] uploadedParams = { typeof(int), typeof(int) };
            Type[] streamParams = { typeHttpRawUploadedContent, typeof(int), typeof(int) };
            Type[] parameters = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeHttpInputStream };
    
            // Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance
            object uploadedContent = typeHttpRawUploadedContent
              .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, uploadedParams, null)
              .Invoke(new object[] { data.Length, data.Length });
    
            // Call the AddBytes method
            typeHttpRawUploadedContent
              .GetMethod("AddBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
              .Invoke(uploadedContent, new object[] { data, 0, data.Length });
    
            // This is necessary if you will be using the returned content (ie to Save)
            typeHttpRawUploadedContent
              .GetMethod("DoneAddingBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
              .Invoke(uploadedContent, null);
    
            // Create an HttpInputStream instance
            object stream = (Stream)typeHttpInputStream
              .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, streamParams, null)
              .Invoke(new object[] { uploadedContent, 0, data.Length });
    
            // Create an HttpPostedFile instance
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile)
              .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameters, null)
              .Invoke(new object[] { filename, contentType, stream });
    
            return postedFile;
        }
```