# how to convert a byte[] to HttpPostedFileBase using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

how to convert byte[] into HttpPostedFileBase using c#. here i have tried the following way.

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localPath);
HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)bytes;
```

I am getting an cannot implicitly convert error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179730/is-it-possible-to-convert-byte-to-httppostedfile

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about creating a custom postedfile? :)

```
public class MemoryPostedFile : HttpPostedFileBase
{
    private readonly byte[] fileBytes;

    public MemoryPostedFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName = null)
    {
        this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.InputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    }

    public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;

    public override string FileName { get; }

    public override Stream InputStream { get; }
}
```

That you can simply use like this:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localPath);
HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(bytes);
```

Comment: The line `private Stream inputStream;` is not needed and not used. I tried to edit the answer but I found out that [we are not supposed to edit each others code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276580/4826084).

Comment: @Oskar you're completely right (about the unnecessary inputStream field) I totally missed that when I wrote the answer. I will update accordingly. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm getting the below error while compiling in below line: Line: public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length; Error:  fileBytes is a field but used like a type. Please help me to resolve @KarlPatrikJohansson

Comment: @Ronak It seems to me that you're using an earlier version of C# that does not allow you to define get-only (readonly) properties with the arrow => operator. You can try replacing `public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;` with `public override int ContentLength { get return fileBytes.Length; }`

Comment: Hi @Zerratar, I used your code and I could assign memorypostedfilebase to httppostedfilebase. But whenever I try to save this memorypostedfilebase  to server, I get error that says method or operation is not implemented . Can u please help me?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class HttpPostedFileBaseCustom: HttpPostedFileBase
{
    MemoryStream stream;
    string contentType;
    string fileName;

    public HttpPostedFileBaseCustom(MemoryStream stream, string contentType, string fileName)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override int ContentLength
    {
        get { return (int)stream.Length; }
    }

    public override string ContentType
    {
        get { return contentType; }
    }

    public override string FileName
    {
        get { return fileName; }
    }

    public override Stream InputStream
    {
        get { return stream; }
    }

}

    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localPath);
    var contentTypeFile = "image/jpeg";
    var fileName = "images.jpeg";
    HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new 
HttpPostedFileBaseCustom(new MemoryStream (bytes), contentTypeFile, fileName);
```

Comment: Please provide some explaination as to why your code snippes solves the problem. More info here: [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this issue still exists or not, however when I have implemented the solution posted by @Zerratar I also encountered the same issue reported by @Jass on May 16, 2021. On checking the decompiled version of System.web I have found that SaveAs method need to be implemented whithout which saving will throw error as expected.

My Implementation is

```
public class FileInStreamFormat : HttpPostedFileBase
{
    private readonly byte[] fileBytes;
    private MemoryStream iStream;

    public FileInStreamFormat(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName, string ContentType)
    {
        this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.ContentType = ContentType;
        this.iStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    }

    public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;

    public override string FileName { get; }

    public override Stream InputStream
    {
        get { return iStream; }
    }

    public override string ContentType { get; }

    public override void SaveAs(string filename)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write))
            iStream.WriteTo(file);
    }
}
```

And the calling is

```
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileObjectStream(Stream fileStreamObj, string fileContentType)
    {
        MemoryStream newMs = new MemoryStream();
        fileStreamObj.CopyTo(newMs);
        byte[] fileByte = newMs.ToArray();
        FileInStreamFormat FISF = new FileInStreamFormat(fileByte, fileName, fileContentType);
        return FISF;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).