# how set HttpPostedFileBase ContentType value in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime

how set HttpPostedFileBase ContentType value in runtime?

```
    HttpPostedFileBase upl=null;
    string path="/exelFile/book1.xlsx";

    //-----Set Name Runtime 
    var Name="FileName.xlsx";
    //-----Set Type Runtime 
    var type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";         
    byte[] bytes =System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(Path));
    upl = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(bytes, Name);

    //=====>how set type
    upl.ContentType 
    //==============
```

Comment: A `HttpPostedFileBase` is for uploading a file from a browser. And its `ContentType` is readonly (it gas a getter only). And what is `MemoryPostedFile`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to MemoryPostedFile to this HttpPostedFileBase. is there  no way ?

Comment: You have not said what `MemoryPostedFile` is. But it makes no sense to do so. What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: I change the value of it in the specific conditions that the file uploads

Comment: Not clear what you mean, but its a [read-only property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know it's read-only .I wanted to know there's no way.Thanks a lot for guidance

Comment: I assume [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094997/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-httppostedfilebase-using-c-sharp) is what your using for `MemoryPostedFile`. In which case just add an extra parameter in the constructor for `ContentType` and override the property (similar to the `FileName` property)

Comment: This is a very good idea. i am try this

Comment: Many thanks to @StephenMuecke. By adding the 'ContentType' to the following function is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to @StephenMuecke. By adding the 'ContentType' to the following function is solved.

```
  public class MemoryPostedFile : HttpPostedFileBase
    {
        private readonly byte[] fileBytes;

        public MemoryPostedFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName = null,string ContentType=null)
        {
            this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
            this.FileName = fileName;
            this.ContentType = ContentType;
            this.InputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
        }

        public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;

        public override string FileName { get; }

        public override string ContentType { get; }

        public override Stream InputStream { get; }
    }
```