# How to change the content type of httppostedfilebase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using HttpPostedFileBase to upload a file using ASP.NET MVC. I need to post this to a API call and i am getting a error

> "StatusCode: 403, Reason Phrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent".

This is because i am passing file content as "application/octet-stream", where as API call wants the content type as "application/vnd.qlik.sense.app". 
Many posts in internet says that HttpPostedFileBase is a read only and we cannot change the content type. Can anybody let me know how we can change the content type of HttpPostedFileBase. Is this possible?

here is my code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFile file)
{    
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
        APIcall.Upload(fileName);
    }  
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519566/how-set-httppostedfilebase-contenttype-value-in-runtime?noredirect=1&lq=1) for an example of how to inherit from `HttpPostedFileBase` to add a setter for `ContentType` in the constructor

Comment: I modified the code as below but file value is coming as blank now.   > [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(MemoryPostedFile  file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                APICall.Upload(fileName);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this here [how set HttpPostedFileBase ContentType value in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519566/how-set-httppostedfilebase-contenttype-value-in-runtime)

```
public class MemoryPostedFile : HttpPostedFileBase
{
    private readonly byte[] fileBytes;

    public MemoryPostedFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName = null,string ContentType=null)
    {
        this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.ContentType = ContentType;
        this.InputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    }

    public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;

    public override string FileName { get; }

    public override string ContentType { get; }

    public override Stream InputStream { get; }
}
```