# Select Linq cannot implicitly convert type byte[] to System.web.httpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a linq select which join multiple table and 1 of the table consist of a byte data type.

My ViewModel is as per below:

```
public class ServiceRequestsViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is as per below:

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceRequestsViewModel> ServiceRequestGetAll()
    {
        var result = (from srv in DB.Services
                      join srq in DB.ServiceRequests on srv.Id equals srq.ServiceId 
                      join srp in DB.ServiceApprovers on srq.ServiceId equals srp.ServiceId
                      select new ServiceRequestsViewModel
                      {
                          Id = srq.Id,
                          ServiceId = srq.ServiceId,
                          RequestorId = srq.RequestorId,
                          ApproverId = srp.UserId,
                          Name = srv.Name,
                          Description = srq.Description,
                          Status = srq.Status,
                          Attachment = srq.Attachment,
                          CreatedBy = srq.CreatedBy,
                          CreatedDate = srq.CreatedDate
                      })
                      ;
        return result.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(a => a.Status).ThenByDescending(b => b.CreatedDate);
    }
```

For the Attachment = srq.Attachment,
I encounter the error: Cannot implicitly convert type byte[] to System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase.

Comment: Please trim this down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- most of the code here has nothing to do with the error message you're seeing.

Comment: While Linq is used, it has nothing to do with the error. I removed that tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a byte\[\] to HttpPostedFileBase using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094997/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-httppostedfilebase-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

`HttpPostedFileBase` is a wrapper class so you can access the data that *your client uploaded with this call*.

You are not in that scenario with your call.

Your data is already in your database. You need to pick a different datatype to return that data to your client. `byte[]` (that you already have) might be fine for your case, we cannot know, that's your job to decide.