# How to convert byte array to HttpPostedFileBase in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, httppostedfilebase

I am using asp.net MVC web application. My requirement is to convert byte array to `HttpPostedFileBase`. I am creating byte array using filepath.

I have taken reference of this question
[how to convert a byte[] to HttpPostedFileBase using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094997/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-httppostedfilebase-using-c-sharp) (answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2678145/zerratar)

When I used that code I am getting exception while saving that converted file to server. Exception is method or operation is not implemented.

I thought I am getting error because, the content type and filename of converted file was returning null.

So I slightly changed the code like this.

```
public class HttpPostedFileForStl : HttpPostedFileBase
{
    private readonly byte[] fileBytes;

    public HttpPostedFileForStl(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName)
    {
        this.fileBytes = fileBytes;
        this.InputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
        this.FileName = fileName;
    }

    public override int ContentLength => fileBytes.Length;
    public override string FileName { get; }
    public override string ContentType { get; } = "application/octet-stream";
    public override Stream InputStream { get; }
}
```

I am passing byte array and filename to this class.
Now I am getting appropriate filename and content type in converted file, but exception is still there. Can anyone help?

Comment: _"Exception is method or operation is not implemented."_ - What method?

Comment: There is no method as such. I get this error while saving converted file using saveas() @Llama

Comment: Please click "Copy details" on the exception and include the full details in your question.

Comment: Look at [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Abstractions/HttpPostedFileBase.cs,9373af24e1d458c3) -- make sure you implement everything even though everything is only virtual.

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft made these `virtual` rather than `abstract`. :/

Comment: @Llama -- yeah that's really goofy.

Comment: @Andy, sorry, but what does it mean? Everything is virtual means can I see set its value or not?

Comment: @Andy  what does it mean?

Comment: I don't see `SaveAs` overriden.

Comment: I am not getting you@Andy

Comment: in your `HttpPostedFileForStl ` class, add `public override void SaveAs(string filename){}`

Comment: @Andy , ok and what should I write inside that method?

Comment: If you add that line, does the issue go away?

Comment: @Andy, Yeah exception goes away. But expected behaviour is to actually save modified file. And that is not being done.

Comment: Can't I actually save it?

Comment: sure -- you have the file name, you have the file bytes.. that's all you need

Comment: Yes , so it should work with file.Saveas(), right? It didn't work. @Andy

Comment: you could try `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, fileBytes);`

Comment: Yeah , how could I not think of it. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class HttpPostedFileBaseCustom : HttpPostedFileBase
    {
        private byte[] _Bytes;
        private String _ContentType;
        private String _FileName;
        private MemoryStream _Stream;

        public override Int32 ContentLength { get { return this._Bytes.Length; } }
        public override String ContentType { get { return this._ContentType; } }
        public override String FileName { get { return this._FileName; } }

        public override Stream InputStream
        {
            get
            {
                if(this._Stream == null)
                {
                    this._Stream = new MemoryStream(this._Bytes);
                }
                return this._Stream;
            }
        }

        public HttpPostedFileBaseCustom(byte[] contentData, String contentType, String fileName)
        {
            this._ContentType = contentType;
            this._FileName = fileName;
            this._Bytes = contentData ?? new byte[0];
        }

        public override void SaveAs(String filename)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, this._Bytes);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: For additional reference, please have a look at this discussion.
https://forums.asp.net/t/1468949.aspx?HttpPostedFileBase+mapping+problem+Anyone+